# How to get xampp/htdocs folder location dynamically using vb.net?

Tags: php, vb.net

How to get xampp/htdocs folder location dynamically using vb.net?
I want to get the current directory of my xampp programmatically using vb.net
is there simple way to or one liner code to get the path of my xampp.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to get c:/xampp/htdocs?

Comment: @McStuffins yes mate

Comment: Nothing is dynamic then... It's constantly in the same place. Just do a scan or something. I dont know the code in VB.NET since I am a PHP developer...